# Tournament Structure Sorting C++

Tags: c++, sorting, structure, tournament

Here I have this code that sorts a tournament structure like array in descending order. It sorts all but one number and always returns a **-1** as the lowest integer it sorts, I have read through this code multiple times and I can't seem to figure out why it's not sorting properly, I'm not sure if it's just missing my eyes or if there is a small typo somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int maxi(int i, int j)
{
  if (i > j) return(i);
  else return(j);
}

int mini(int i, int j)
{
  if (i < j) return(i);
  else return (j);
}

int buildtourn(int tourn[], int n)
{
  int min1=0, a;
  //Compute tournament structure
for (int i=2*n-2; i>1; i=i-2)
   {
    tourn[i/2] = maxi(tourn[i], tourn[i+1]);
    a=mini(tourn[i], tourn[i+1]);
    if (min1>a) min1=a;
    }
    return min1;
}

int getnext(int tourn[], int n, int low)
{
int i = 2;
//Part 1 - downward traversal
while (i <= 2*n-1)
{
    if (tourn[i]>tourn[i+1])
    {
        tourn[i]=low;
        i=2*i;
    }
    else
    {
        tourn[i+1]=low;
        i=2*(i+1);
    }
}

//Part 2 - upward traversal
for (i = i/2; i>1; i=i/2)
{
    if (i%2==0) tourn[i/2]=maxi(tourn[i],tourn[i+1]); // go to the right of i
    else tourn[i/2]=maxi(tourn[i], tourn[i-1]); // to the left of i
}
return 0;
}
int main()
{
int tourn[100], n, i, low;
//Read
cout << "Give n :" ;
cin >> n;
cout<< "Enter the integers to be sorted : " << endl;
for (i=n; i<=2*n-1; i++)
    cin >> tourn[i];

//build tournament
low=buildtourn(tourn,n)-1;

//Sorting
cout << " Sorted items are : " << endl;
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    cout << tourn[i] << '\t';
    getnext(tourn,n,low);
}
cout << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

I believe the error lies solely in my function that builds the tournament structure but, i'm not quite sure if i'm looking in the wrong place.

```
int buildtourn(int tourn[], int n)
{
  int min1=0, a;
  //Compute tournament structure
  for (int i=2*n-2; i>1; i=i-2)
  {
    tourn[i/2] = maxi(tourn[i], tourn[i+1]);
    a=mini(tourn[i], tourn[i+1]);
    if (min1>a) min1=a;
  }
return min1;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help and If I need to add anymore details to this problem please let me know in the comments.

EDIT: This is a link to view the output i am receiving. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5oNK.jpg

EDIT 2: If i were to use the numbers 20 14 1 3 8 to be sorted, it would sort them as **20 8 1 3 -1**

Comment: Please read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. How do you know it does not sort properly? You should include input, actual and expected output in the question

Comment: Perhaps if you properly indented your code, so that it's actually readable, it might be easier to see the problem.

Comment: @tobi303 I apologize, i've edited it to include a link of the output I am recieving

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I copy pasted straight the program i was using to make this, I will fix that as well.

Comment: Ok, now your question has a different problem: questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself, instead of links to external web sites that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do not have the reputation to include embedded images, It only lets me provide links

Comment: Who said anything about images? In fact, images are discouraged, and if you include a useless image in your question it will be quickly downvoted. I see nothing that you can't mention here as plain text. Your program is not drawing a graph. It's output should be plain text and you must include as such, instead of some utterly useless image.

Comment: why `int min1=0` ? should'nt it be initialized with a greater value like `MAX_INT` since it can only decrease ?

Comment: @Franck I was thinking i only had to initialize this variable since it is assigned a new value within the function? Or is that the wrong way of thinking?

Comment: Where is it assigned to a new value ? I only see `if (min1>a) min1=a;` so if all `a` are `>= 0` it will never be assigned.

Comment: I can't make sense of your Tournament sort algorithm. Did the instructor give this to you or did you make it up or copy it from somewhere?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani it was given by an instructor

Answer (score 0):

In mini maxi functions, replace < and > by <= and >=